# Is there a more efficient way to write this function involving FontAwesome icons?

Tags: javascript

I have this little function that changes the FontAwesome icon on the click of a button from the "chevron down" to the "chevron down". I have a feeling that there's a much more efficient way to write this function below:

```
 const moveChevron = () => {
    if (chevron.classList.contains("fa-chevron-down")) {
      chevron.classList.remove("fa-chevron-down");
      chevron.classList.add("fa-chevron-up");
    } else if (chevron.classList.contains("fa-chevron-up")) {
      chevron.classList.remove("fa-chevron-up");
      chevron.classList.add("fa-chevron-down");
    }
  };

searchCheck.addEventListener('click', moveChevron);
```

Is there a way to streamline this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle class (put it 'on' if it was in 'off' state and backwards):

```js
const moveChevron = () => {
    chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down");
    chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up");
};
```

Of course before doing that your element must have either one or another class set by default:

```html
<input type="check" class="fa-chevron-down" id="my-check-box />
```

Comment: Ah I tried that at first, but I didn't toggle the second class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Element.classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) can shorten the function like so:

```
const moveChevron = () => {
    chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up");
    chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The class list has a [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method that can be applied in a few different ways. In isolation, you could do this, toggling both classes:

```js
const moveChevron = () => {
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down");
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up");
};
```

But it seems likely that you’ll want to implement some behaviour based on this state beyond just toggling a class. In that case, you have to choose where you want to keep the state. Maybe in the classes, making use of the return value of `toggle` (a boolean according to whether the class is present after the toggling)? Maybe in a variable:

```js
// name this according to what the chevron means
let isFoo = true;

const moveChevron = () => {
  isFoo = !isFoo;

  // select !isFoo or isFoo for these for best readability
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down", !isFoo);
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up", isFoo);
};
```

Or maybe best of all, in a control the browser knows how to work with. One control that’s toggleable is a checkbox, and it’s highly possible you should be using one somewhere. Maybe `searchCheck` is already a checkbox – its name sort of implies that. In that case, the correct event is “change” and the state is in its `checked` property, don’t keep track of it separately:

```js
const moveChevron = () => {
  var isFoo = searchCheck.checked;
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down", !isFoo);
  chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up", isFoo);
};
```

And it’s possible you can even implement the above in CSS using `:checked`, avoiding JavaScript entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use toggle method in place of individual Add/Remove methods.**

```js
let chevron = document.getElementById("chevron");
let searchCheck = document.getElementById("searchCheck");

const moveChevron = () => {
    if (chevron.classList.contains("fa-chevron-down")) {
      chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-up");
    } else if (chevron.classList.contains("fa-chevron-up")) {
      chevron.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-down");
    }
  };

searchCheck.addEventListener('click', moveChevron);
```

```css
#searchCheck {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#chevron {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f90;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="searchCheck">Change Icon</button>
    <span id="chevron" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```